# bash - pick a number from a list and print a specific output

Tags: bash, printf

I have made a script that asks you for a string, then you need to select a number from a list and, if you actually chose a number, the program will print the string but with a style and the thing you need to write to apply the style you chose to the string (code down below)
is there any way to make this shorter? (expecially the if and elif statements)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Hello, who am I talking to?"
# Get string from user input
read -p 'String: ' string
echo $string
echo "Please select a modifier from this list by typing the modifier\'s number."
# List possible styles that can be applied to the string
printf '\e[1;4;33m[1] Bold string\n'
printf '\e[4;33m[2] Underlined string\n\e[0;33m'
printf '\e[30;47m[3] Black foreground\n\e[0;33m'
printf '\e[31;47m[4] Red foreground\n'
printf '\e[32m[5] Green foreground\n'
printf '\e[33m[6] Yellow foreground\n'
printf '\e[34m[7] Blue foreground\n'
printf '\e[35m[8] Purple foreground\n'
printf '\e[36m[9] Cyan foreground\n'
printf '\e[0;37;40m[10] White foreground\n\e[0;33m'
printf '\e[1;4;33m[11] Black background\n'
printf '\e[1;4;33m[12] Red background\n'
printf '\e[1;4;33m[13] Green background\n'
printf '\e[1;4;33m[14] Yellow background\n'
printf '\e[1;4;33m[15] Blue background\n'
printf '\e[1;4;33m[16] Purple background\n'
printf '\e[1;4;33m[17] Cyan background\n'
printf '\e[1;4;33m[18] White background\n\e[0;37m'
# Ask user to choose a style to apply
read -p 'Number: ' number
# Check if the number is between 1 and 18
if ! [[ $number =~ ^([1-9]|1[018])$ ]]
then
        echo 'Please only select a number from 1 to 18'
fi
# If the number that the user chose is 1, print a bold string
if [[ $number = 1 ]]
then
        printf "\e[1;37m${string}\n"
        echo "\e[1;37m${string}\n"
elif [[ $number = 2 ]]
then
        printf "\e[4;37m${string}\n"
        echo "\e[4;37m${string}\n"
#(etc.)
```

Comment: you should probably ask your question here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Short answer : yes you can, a lot of lines are similar and you can create functions to reduce the duplication of code and loop over some list of styles.

Comment: @CorentinLimier if it is actually possible, how can I do that? (I mean what's the code that I should change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the codes and colour names in arrays, then just use a loop to iterate over them.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

colors=("",
        'Bold string'
        'Underlined string'
        'Black foreground'
        'Red foreground'
        'Green foreground'
        'Yellow foreground'
        'Blue foreground'
        'Purple foreground'
        'Cyan foreground'
        'White foreground'
        'Black background'
        'Red background'
        'Green background'
        'Yellow background'
        'Blue background'
        'Purple background'
        'Cyan background'
        'White background')
codes=("", '1' '4' '30;47' '31' '32' '33' '34' '35' '36' '0;37;40' '39' '41'
       '42' '43' '44' '45' '46' '47')

read -p 'Hello, who am I talking to? ' string
echo "Hello, $string!"
echo "Please select a modifier from this list by typing the modifier's number."

for i in {1..18} ; do
    printf '\e[%sm[%d] %s\e[m\n' "${codes[i]}" $i "${colors[i]}"
done;

read -p 'Your choice? (number) ' number
if ! [[ $number =~ ^([1-9]|1[0-8])$ ]]
then
        echo 'Please only select a number from 1 to 18'
else
    printf '\e[%sm%s\e[m\n' "${codes[number]}" "$string"
fi
```

Other changes I did:

- Use the Prompt to ask the question
- Set the colour off after printing it
- No need to backslash a single quote inside double quotes
- The regex to check the number was wrong, I fixed it.